# tf.initializers.constant doesn't initialize using arrays (Tensorflow js)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

==Tensorflow JS==

I'm trying to make a simple initializer. But, instead of using a constant value, I'd like to specify the weights of the kernel. Yet, it seems I'm unable to provide the right format. I keep getting the error: **value must be a primitive**

Here is my code:

```js
//Simple input
var input = tf.layers.input({ shape: [1, 1, 1] });
//Very basic Conv2d
var q = tf.layers.conv2d({
  filters: 1,
  kernelSize: 1,
  useBias: false,
  kernelInitializer: tf.initializers.constant({
    value: [1],
  }),
});
//Error when applying
q.apply(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all:

> value must be a primitive.

It indicates that value cannot be an array, but a primitive value such as number. Therefore, it should rather be: `value: 1` .

```
var input = tf.layers.input({ shape: [1, 1, 1] });
//Very basic Conv2d
var q = tf.layers.conv2d({
  filters: 1,
  kernelSize: 1,
  useBias: false,
  kernelInitializer: tf.initializers.constant({
    value: 1,
  }),
});
//Error when applying
q.apply(input);
```

Comment: Not exactly. I trimmed the rest of error message which says it can be an array of primitives.

Comment: Do you have the error when you use a primitive instead of an array ?

Comment: I'd be cheating you if I said you solved the problem. The actual solution is to create a new initializer. I might share the answer once I have the time.